# Rails:How to fix ActiveRecord::Irreversible Order Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I get the following error:

```
2.4.1 :001 > Blogger.last
ActiveRecord::IrreversibleOrderError: Relation has no current order and table has no primary key to be used as default order from (irb):1
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Further information:

Blogger.first seems to work:

```
Blogger.first
Blogger Load (3.6ms)  SELECT  "bloggers".* FROM "bloggers" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]

#<Blogger id: 1, blogger_id: 502, deadline: nil, reminded: nil, needsreminder: nil, created_at: "2018-03-13 12:10:09", updated_at: "2018-03-13 12:10:09", interests: "Ethik, Gesellschaft, Kultur, Logik, Wissen, Wissen...">
```

Bloggers were created with a seed:

```
Blogger.create!([
  {id: 1, blogger_id: 502, deadline: nil, reminded: nil, needsreminder: nil, interests: "Ethik, Gesellschaft, Kultur, Logik, Wissen, Wissenschaft"},
  {id: 2, blogger_id: 453, deadline: nil, reminded: nil, needsreminder: nil, interests: "Ethik, Gesellschaft, Kultur"},
  {id: 3, blogger_id: 434, deadline: nil, reminded: nil, needsreminder: nil, interests: "Menschsein und Sprache"},
  {id: 4, blogger_id: 370, deadline: nil, reminded: nil, needsreminder: nil, interests: "Ethik, Gesellschaft, Kultur"},
  {id: 5, blogger_id: 485, deadline: nil, reminded: nil, needsreminder: nil, interests: "Unbekannt"}
])
```

These are the migrations for Blogger:

```
class CreateBloggers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :bloggers do |t|
      t.integer :blogger_id
      t.date :deadline
      t.date :reminded
      t.boolean :needsreminder

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class AddInterestsToBloggers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :bloggers, :interests, :string
  end
end
```

Blogger.rb

```
class Blogger < ApplicationRecord


end
```

Rails: 5.1.4

Ruby: 2.4.1

Postgresql: PostgreSQL 9.5.12 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit

Comment: Can you show the SQL generated when executing `Blogger.first`?

Comment: Also is there a `default_scope` defined on `Blogger`?

Comment: @MoMolog I updated my question. Scopes are defined in blogger.rb, right? I don't see anything in Blogger.rb

Answer (score 2):

I've just added `primary_key` and it works:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :id
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I rolled back my migrations and then migrated them again.

```
rails db:rollback
rails db:migrate
rails db:seed
```

After that, the error does not occur again:

```
2.4.1 :002 > Blogger.last
  Blogger Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "bloggers".* FROM "bloggers" ORDER BY "bloggers"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Blogger id: 5, blogger_id: 485, deadline: nil, reminded: nil, needsreminder: nil, created_at: "2018-03-13 19:58:33", updated_at: "2018-03-13 19:58:33", interests: "Unbekannt"> 
2.4.1 :003 >
```

However, I'd still be happy if someone could explain what to do if this kind of error happens.

Comment: I stumbled with the same error. Found out that there was missing PRIMARY KEY constraint on the table. Without rollback, updated the database and created the primary key index, which fixed the issue.

If you go check the source it says: " IrreversibleOrderError is raised when a relation's order is too complex for +reverse_order+ to automatically reverse."

Answer (score 1):

I simply re-specified the primary key without mentioning anything in the model file.

Note: I actually created a new table using an existing one and landed in this error.

I specified below in my migration file after create table,

`execute "ALTER TABLE items ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"`